# How do I preserve vimcat colors in a pipe?

Tags: vim, pipe, colors, ansi

For example, this will preserve `ls`'s coloring / syntax highlighting:

```bsh
ls -la --color=always | egrep --color=always -i "(foobar|$)"
```

But this will not (so I know it's not a grep issue):

```bsh
vimcat /etc/apt/sources.list | egrep --color=always -i "(foobar|$)"
```

Alternate solutions that don't use vimcat (but instead directly call vim) are acceptable, so long as the output is not paginated.

Comment: Noob!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: (: (: Troll. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing! The problem was simply that sources.list wasn't a highlightable file; a different file worked just fine. So nevermind. :) Ziggoto's answer is still interesting, so I'll leave this question around without deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility tool called [faketty](https://github.com/dtolnay/faketty) that wraps your command in a pty, even when you're using redirections (like pipes).

I believe if you do, you may get the result you expect

```
faketty vimcat /etc/apt/sources.list | egrep --color=always -i "(foobar|$)"
```